# Calculate number of trials to get uniques

Tags: python, statistics, julia, probability

Given the following table

```
Type     Chance Number of unique elements 
common   30.00%  21
Uncommon 30.00%  27
Rare     20.00%  32
Ultra    15.00%  14
Epic     5.00%   10
```

Is there a way to calculate with a python script the average trials necessary to get X amount of unique elements across all the types (I.e. 5 elements that I do not own, regardless if they are common or uncommon etc...)?

Comment: You mean you want to get at least one element in each type?

Comment: Better post this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics

Comment: No I mean that I want an element that I do not own. Let's say I want 5 uniques: it is fine to get 5 commons, or 3 commons and 2 epics as long as those two epics are not the same epics (i.e. Epic A and Epic B is fine but not 2 Epic A)

Comment: Aha! Ok, I assume that you pick an element at random and put it back, then repeat the process. The elements of each type are uniformly distributed.

Comment: Correct! And I need a python solution. I have explored math solutions and are too complex

Comment: Ok, I will propose a solution in pseudocode to get you do it step by step. That seems to be a homework or project of some sort.

Comment: Nah, I want to calculate how much I have to spend in a mobile game to complete my collection :D

Comment: LOL. Ok, let me give it a shot then. I need some time.

Comment: One more question: I assume after you get X unique elements, you continue drawing elements taking into account the remaining items. Example: After drawing 8 items, you get 5 uniques ones and you are left with 3 other items. You consume the 5 items and continue until you get 5 unique items again.

Comment: No you keep owning them. I want to build a table that says to get 1 character you need 1 pull on average, to get two characters (unique, regardless rarity) you need X pulls, to get 3 characters you need Y pulls, until you reach 104 (total characters) and Z pulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this is the solution:

```python
from numpy.random import multinomial
import numpy as np

class UniqueElements:
    def __init__(self, type_dist, unique_elements):
        self.type_dist = type_dist
        self.unique_elements = unique_elements
        self.unique_elements_dist = [[1.0 / n for i in range(n)] for n in unique_elements]
        self.init_items()
        
    def pickone(self, dist):
        return np.where(multinomial(1, dist) == 1)[0][0]
    
    def init_items(self):
        self.items = np.zeros((len(self.type_dist), max(self.unique_elements)), dtype=int)
    
    def draw(self):
        item_type = self.pickone(self.type_dist)
        item_number = self.pickone(self.unique_elements_dist[item_type])
        return item_type, item_number
    
    def draw_unique(self, x):
        while (self.items > 0).sum() < x:
            item_type, item_number = self.draw()
            self.items[item_type, item_number] += 1
        return self.items.sum()
    
    def average_for_unique(self, x, n, reset=True):
        tot_draws = 0
        for i in range(n):
            tot_draws += self.draw_unique(x)
            if reset:
                self.init_items()
            else:
                self.items[self.items>1] -= 1

        return tot_draws / n
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    type_dist = [0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.05]
    unique_elements = [21, 27, 32, 14, 10]
    ue = UniqueElements(type_dist, unique_elements)
    print(ue.average_for_unique(10, 100000))
```

If you want to put each completed set aside and continue with whatever remains, change the last line as follows:
`print(ue.average_for_unique(10, 100000, reset=False))`

Note: For x = 5, the average is 5.1, for x = 8, the average is 8.3. This is not surprising as there are 104 unique elements across the different types.

For the sake of demo, this is the same program using Julia programming language:

```julia
using Random

function pickone(dist)
    n = length(dist)
    i = 1
    r = rand()
    while r >= dist[i] && i<n 
        i+=1
    end
    return i
end  

function init_items(type_dist, unique_elements)
    return zeros(Int32, length(type_dist), maximum(unique_elements))
end

function draw(type_dist, unique_elements_dist)
    item_type = pickone(type_dist)
    item_number = pickone(unique_elements_dist[item_type])
    return item_type, item_number
end

function draw_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, items, x)
    while sum(items .> 0) < x
        item_type, item_number = draw(type_dist, unique_elements_dist)
        items[item_type, item_number] += 1
    end
    return sum(items)
end

function average_for_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, x, n, reset=true)
    println("Started computing...")
    items = init_items(type_dist, unique_elements)

    tot_draws = 0
    for i in 1:n
        tot_draws += draw_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, items, x)
        if reset
            items .= 0
        else
            items[items.>1] -= 1
        end
    end

    return tot_draws / n
end
    
type_dist = [0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.05]
type_dist = cumsum(type_dist)

unique_elements = [21, 27, 32, 14, 10]
unique_elements_dist = [[1 / unique_elements[j] for i in 1:unique_elements[j]] for j in 1:length(unique_elements)]
unique_elements_dist = [cumsum(dist) for dist in unique_elements_dist]

avg = average_for_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, 10, 100000)
print(avg)
```

Longer startup time, especially while downloading and compiling packages. After that, it's blazing fast.

Anyone can improve the Python version to match the Julia version? 100 points bounty.

Comment: `Random` is part of base Julia, you don't need to install it with the pkg manager

Comment: @MarcIttel Thanks for your comment. Will remove.